# Getting MULE:SOURCE_RESPONSE_SEND while using FTP/SFTP connector in Mule API

Tags: ftp, mule, sftp, batch-processing, mule4

I have 2 APIs:

- system API: which is reading a file from the SFTP server
- process API: processing the file coming from system API and sending data to backend using batch

I am transforming the payload coming from the read connector in system API to `application/csv`. Also, I am converting the CSV payload to application/java before inserting the records into the batch.

The process API is working correctly (data going to backend) but in the logs, I am seeing `MULE:SOURCE_RESPONSE_SEND`.

`Root Exception stack trace: java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempted to send invalid data through the HTTP response.`

When I am changing the error response of HTTP listener to simple String "Data processing completed". This is the payload I am seeing as a response.

Where exactly might be this error `Root Exception stack trace: java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempted to send invalid data through HTTP response` coming from?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add the complete text of the error plus stack trace to the question. It would be helpful if you enable mule verbose exceptions first if possible.
You mention this is related to SFTP but there mention of an SFTP operation nor any symptoms related to it directly. You should try to isolate the issue to the process or system API first. If the issue is in the later it would appear that there is no relation to SFTP.
Also since this is a problem related to the data you should provide example data, and what transformations are being done in the flow to said data.

Comment: Forgot to ask: versions of mule 4, HTTP connector, SFTP connector and any patches or cumulative patches?